# Calculate directional derivative and find equation of a plane tangent to function plot

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

I'm given the following problem:
Calculate directional derivative of a function $$f(x,y) = x^2 - xy + 3y^2$$ at point $$(1,0)$$ in the direction of a vector $$v = (3,4)$$ and provide the equation of a plane tangent to plot of said function at point $$(1, 0, 0)$$
I'd be very thankful if someone could show me how to approach this problem. I know how to calculate partial derivatives, but I'm not sure how to calculate directional derivative and find plane equation.

Comment: cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3648415/how-to-find-directional-derivative)

Answer (score 0):

For differentiable functions, which is the case here, the directional derivative can be computed as $f'_{(v_1,v_2)}(a,b) = v_1 f'_x(a,b) + v_2 f'_y(a,b)$, i.e.
$$
f'_{(3,4)}(1,0) = 3 f'_x(1,0) + 4f'_y(1,0)= 3 \times 2 + 4 \times (-1) =2
$$

Regarding the equation of the plane, it will be of the form
$$
z-1 = 2(x-1) + (-1)(y-0)\Leftrightarrow 2x-y-z = 1.
$$

Comment: Do you know why according to this I am getting a result of 2/5 instead of 2? https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-3/directional-derivative-calculator/?f=x%5E2+-+xy+%2B+3y%5E2&p=x%2Cy%3D1%2C0&v=3%2C4&steps=on

Comment: @user747644 This just depends on the definition of direction derivative you are using in your class... If you are using vector with norm 1, the answer is in fact $\frac{2}{\|(3,4)\|}=\frac 25$. If this restriction is not being imposed, the result is 2.